# Наиболее благоприятный вид ссылок для поисковых систем

Tags: seo

Я сделал таким образом: http://site.ru/?page=feedback и т.д., а потом подумал не будет ли это ядом для поисковых систем? Подскажите пож-та. И ещё стоит ли изменять вид ссылок на http://site.ru/feedback/ через .htacces? Какой вид ссылок будет наиболее лучший для поисковых систем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поисковики смотрят на адресс ссылки и учитывают его при ранжировании, поэтому однозначно делай, помимо всего прочего такие ссылки(ЧПУ) облегчают жизнь пользователям

Answer (score 2):

http://site.ru/feedback/ благоприятнее, чем http://site.ru/?page=feedback

http://site.ru/news/ya_poshel_gulyat_na_ulicu.html благоприятнее, чем http://site.ru/news/12153.html

Comment: новость мирового масштаба=)

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ. 
Из моего ответа следует, что ссылки стоит менять.

Comment: Да для пользователя это пофиг, кто туда смотрит, я стараюсь для поисковых систем

Comment: А. Лебедев утверждает, что ссылки должны строится таким образом, что удалив часть ссылки слева до первого слэша, пользователь должен попасть на логический уровень выше, если это возможно

Comment: А что делать, если если нужно передать какой-то параметр например ид товара http://site.ru/?page=products&id=81, как такую ссылку записать?

Comment: очевиднo, http://site.ru/products/81/
а в /products/ - список товаров / категорий товаров

Comment: по этой теме почитайте про REST архитектуру построения URL

Comment: А как же потом получить этот параметр в переменную? Также: $id=$_GET['id']?

Comment: в соответсвующем роутере укажешь что это id и всё, на самом деле эти записи ссылок:

- ``http://site.ru/products/81/``
- ``http://site.ru/products/?id=81``

эквиваленты, просто первый с эстетической точки зрения более приемлим